# Getting always false value for the isExtensionAvailable with CameraX for Bokeh and HDR vendor effects

Tags: android, android-camerax

**What I am trying?**

Enable vendor effects like Bokeh and HDR.

**What I have tried?**

I have tried below code with the Pixel-2 emulator and  Samsung Galaxy S9+ device:

```
val hdrImageCapture = HdrImageCaptureExtender.create(imageCaptureConfig)
        if (hdrImageCapture.isExtensionAvailable)
            hdrImageCapture.enableExtension()

val bokehImageCapture = BokehImageCaptureExtender.create(imageCaptureConfig)
        if (bokehImageCapture.isExtensionAvailable)
            bokehImageCapture.enableExtension()
```

But always getting `false` value when checking `isExtensionAvailable`.

**Dependencies:**

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices that you are testing on doesn't support extension. 
Please check list of supported devices here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/camera-extensions/ExtensionsSupportedDevices.md

Comment: Now a days almost phone camera have functionality of HDR then what else is required to support the extension?

Comment: @SANAT It is not just about device capabilities,  For camerax extension to work, device vendor has to implement CameraX extension interfaces.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-loader-release/camera/extensions/ExtensionsSupportedDevices.md but this list seems outdated. Apparently it's difficult for Google to get OEMs to join in this effort. It's a shame because the photos by cameraX are just bad right now in comparison to the default camera app on the device.

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak , There is lots of new devices been added and tested. 
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/devices